# Is Hibernate / JPA taking in consideration the transient modifier ( not the annotation )

Tags: java, hibernate, serialization, jpa, persistence

I want to avoid serialisation ( in JMS / AMF ) but still persist the field with JPA/Hibernate.

Is the `transient` modifier my friend ? Are `@Transient` annotation and the `transient` modifier related or not a all ?

The java specification precise that a transient field will not be saved to a persistent storage by a system service. But is hibernate a system service ? ( i dont think so )
http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/classes.doc.html#78119

And `java.io.Serialisable` seams to indicate that a `out.writeObject` `and in.readObject` are called for serialisation 
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html

Any insight ?

Maybe should i just write a quick test, but i will be more confident with a piece of spec.

Thank !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is the `transient` modifier my friend ? Are `@Transient` annotation and the `transient` modifier related or not a all ?

They are not *really* related but I'm afraid they won't be your friend anyway, `transient` properties aren't persisted by Hibernate/JPA. The JPA specification puts it like this:

> #### 2.1.1 Persistent Fields and Properties
>
> The persistent state of an entity is
>   accessed by the persistence provider
>   runtime either via JavaBeans style
>   property accessors or via instance
>   variables. A single access type (field
>   or property access) applies to an
>   entity hierarchy. When annotations are
>   used, the placement of the mapping
>   annotations on either the persistent
>   fields or persistent properties of the
>   entity class specifies the access type
>   as being either field - or property -
>   based access respectively.
>
> - If the entity has field-based access, the persistence provider
>     runtime accesses instance variables
>     directly. **All non-`transient`
>     instance variables that are not
>     annotated with the `Transient`**
>     annotation are persistent. When
>     field-based access is used, the
>     object/relational mapping annotations
>     for the entity class annotate the
>     instance variables.
> - If the entity has property-based access, the persistence provider
>     runtime accesses persistent state via
>     the property accessor methods. All
>     properties not annotated with the
>     `Transient` annotation are persistent.
>     The property accessor methods must be
>     public or protected. When
>     property-based access is used, the
>     object/relational mapping annotations
>     for the entity class annotate the
>     getter property accessors.
> - **Mapping annotations cannot be applied to fields or properties that
>     are `transient` or `Transient`**.
> - The behavior is unspecified if mapping annotations are applied to
>     both persistent fields and properties
>     or if the XML descriptor specifies use
>     of different access types within a
>     class hierarchy.
>
> ...

#### References

- JPA 1.0 specification

  - Section 2.1.1 Persistent Fields
- Hibernate Core Reference Guide

  - [2.2.2. Mapping simple properties](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-property)

#### Related questions

- [Why does JPA have a @Transient annotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154622/why-does-jpa-have-a-transient-annotation/)

Answer (score 3):

The part of JPA specification posted by Pascal Thivent looks rather confusing. Actually, Hibernate respects `transient` when field access is used, but ignores in the case of property access. Perhaps it's a Hibernate-specifc behaviour.

For example, in this case `bar` is not serialized, but still persisted to the database:

```
@Entity
@Access(AccessType.FIELD) // Default access type - field
public class Foo {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    transient private String bar;
    ...
    @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY) // Override default access type for this property
    public String getBar() { return bar; }
}
```

**EDIT:** Since it's unclear how this behaviour conforms to the JPA Specification, perhaps the better choice is to use different names for the `transient` field and the corresponding property.

Comment: Interesting... and surprising, the section [2.2.2. Mapping simple properties](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-property) is pretty explicit. Obviously, this would cause problems with the merge of detached entities but it's interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Try to provide `writeObject(ObjectOutputStream oos)` implementation which doesn't make a call to `oos.defaultWriteObject()` but manually writes all necessary properties.

But I'm not sure that this can work, google whether or not it's strictly necessary to call `defaultWriteObject` first.

Comment: It's a working solution. But i would like to avoid it if i can :)