# @Transient not working in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, transient

I am using hibernate 4.1.9.
My code is

```
@Transient
private String ldapIdTemp;
```

package is

```
import javax.persistence.Transient;
```

Still in hibernate query, it is not working and putting the attribute in the query.

part of query snippet (assetasset0_.ldapIdTemp as ldapIdTemp16_0_, )

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Can you try creating setter and getter for the field and annotate the get method with `@Transient`, as follows:

```
private String ldapIdTemp;

 @Transient
 public String getLdapIdTemp() {
    return ldapIdTemp;
 }

 public void setLdapIdTemp(String ldapIdTemp) {
    this.ldapIdTemp = ldapIdTemp;
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

Much depends on how you "integrated" this field in your `Entity` or class hierarchy. Moreover, *field* vs. *property*-access could cause an issue for your setting. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3976590/2849346) for a detailed explanation.

In your case, I could imagine that you either:

1. mixed field and property-access in your entity inheritance strategy
2. use XML-based configuration for Hibernate in your application.

In both cases the [JPA 2.0/2.1 specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/persistence-2_0-final-spec.pdf) clearly states in Section 2.3.1:

> It is an error if a default access type cannot be determined and an access type is not explicitly specified
>   by means of annotations or the XML descriptor. The behavior of applications that **mix** the placement of
>   annotations on fields and properties within an entity hierarchy without explicitly specifying the
>   Access annotation is undefined.

Please check that your persistent `Entity` classes have either *field* OR *property*-based annotations.

Answer (score 2):

Check the `@Transient` annotation fully qualified name.
It can be from either,
`org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient` or `javax.persistence.Transient`.

Try to use `javax.persistence.Transient`.

Comment: This was my problem.  A previous coder had annotated a method using `java.beans.Transient` when the method didn't need the annotation because its name did not look like a getter or setter.  His code ran, but when I used the same annotation on a new method that looked like a getter, the code failed.  I switched to `javax.persistence.Transient` and the code ran.