# adding transient modifier to a non-owning @OneToMany(mappedBy="") relation

Tags: jpa, gson, ejb, java-ee-6

This question is similar/related to this [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976469/is-hibernate-jpa-taking-in-consideration-the-transiant-modifier-not-the-anno), but more specifically focused on a non-owning `@OneToMany` relation side. Given the following mapped getter:

```
...
private List<Leaf> leaves;
...
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "extkey")
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.TRUE)
public List<Leaf> getLeaves() {
    return leaves;
}
...
```

**What would be the impact of adding the `transient` modifier to `leaves` field in this case?**

The relation is lazy and 'reversed', ie the owning side is `Leaf` object. The code was working before and looks working still now, but I wonder about any undesired subtle side effect, since `transient` has some peculiarity in JPA context. I needed this as passing the entity instance to an external Gson lib would loop and `stackoverflow`, I guess bc the bi-directional relation creates a loop and I could avoid it [using transient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802887/gson-how-to-exclude-specific-fields-from-serialization-without-annotations) field. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The impact will be when you deserialize your entity since the object state will be different after serialization.

Anyway, you didn't specify why you needed this modifier.

Comment: I added the reason, sadly I have no control over that lib so that's quite unrelevant to me

Comment: No, you didn't. I re-read your question and there's no reference to why you needed transient.

Comment: "I needed this as passing the entity instance to an external Gson lib would loop and stackoverflow [...]" do you think it's not clear?

Comment: Yes, it's not clear. What Gson lib? What StackOverflow error? Why would transient solve that? Sounds like you needed something like `@JsonIgnore`.

Comment: AFAIK there's no such annotation in gson, you could do it with plain transient, @Expose and excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation(), or ExclusionStrategy. Having a little time, the first was the easiest to choose

Comment: I've never used Gson, so I can't help you with that. You need to ask the framework developers for a solution.