# Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer]

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I am developing an application with Hibernate and I get an Exception when I connect with database. The exception is:

```
Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer]
```

My mapping file is:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.cartif.database.SetPoint" table="SetPoint">
    <id name="iSetPointId" column="setpointid" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <generator class="sequence">
            <param name="sequence">s_setpoint</param>
        </generator>
    </id>
    <property column="sensorType" generated="never" lazy="false" name="sSensortype" type="java.lang.String"/>
    <property column="value" generated="never" lazy="false" name="dValue" type="java.lang.Double"/>
    <property column="relationship" generated="never" lazy="false" name="sRelation" type="java.lang.String"/>
    <property column="deviceid" generated="never" lazy="false" name="iDeviceId" type="java.lang.Integer"/>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And the class with getters/setters which are not included:

```
public class SetPoint {
    private int iSetPointId;
    private String sSensorType;
    private double dValue;
    private String sRelationship;
    private int iDeviceId;
}
```

I have `javassist.jar` included into classpath. I do not know what is the problem. Someone would help me please.

Thanks!

---

I found when the error is launched. If I include properties in mapping file exception is thrown. If I only declare id of table, the exception is not thrown. What is the possible cause?

---

The complete stacktrace is:

```
162980 [btpool0-2 - /Gateway/zigbeedriver/app] ERROR org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.BasicLazyInitializer  - Javassist Enhancement failed: com.cartif.database.ApplicationField
java.lang.RuntimeException: by java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:   javassist/util/proxy/ProxyObject
at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass(ProxyFactory.java:174)
at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.getProxyFactory(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:162)
at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistProxyFactory.postInstantiate(JavassistProxyFactory.java:65)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildProxyFactory(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:185)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.<init>(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:167)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.<init>(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:77)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor12.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:105)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructDefaultTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:133)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.<init>(EntityEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.java:80)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:322)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:485)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:133)
at org.hibernate.persister.PersisterFactory.createClassPersister(PersisterFactory.java:84)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:286)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1845)
at com.db.manager.DatabaseManager.createSession(DatabaseManager.java:74)
at com.db.manager.DatabaseManager.loadObject(DatabaseManager.java:95)
at com.cartif.database.User.loadUser(User.java:53)
at com.cartif.database.User.checkUser(User.java:57)
at com.cartif.zigbee.ZigbeeDriverImpl.checkUser(ZigbeeDriverImpl.java:124)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)
at org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.internal.aop.ServiceInvoker.doInvoke(ServiceInvoker.java:58)
at org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.internal.aop.ServiceInvoker.invoke(ServiceInvoker.java:62)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
at org.springframework.osgi.service.util.internal.aop.ServiceTCCLInterceptor.invokeUnprivileged(ServiceTCCLInterceptor.java:56)
at org.springframework.osgi.service.util.internal.aop.ServiceTCCLInterceptor.invoke(ServiceTCCLInterceptor.java:39)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
at org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.LocalBundleContextAdvice.invoke(LocalBundleContextAdvice.java:59)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
at $Proxy21.checkUser(Unknown Source)
at main.com.cartif.app.server.AppServiceImpl.getUser(AppServiceImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:569)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at main.com.cartif.app.server.AppServiceImpl.service(AppServiceImpl.java:33)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:362)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:726)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:206)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:320)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:842)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:648)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
at org.mortbay.thread.BoundedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(BoundedThreadPool.java:450)
Caused by: javassist.CannotCompileException: by java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javassist/util/proxy/ProxyObject
at javassist.util.proxy.FactoryHelper.toClass(FactoryHelper.java:167)
at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass(ProxyFactory.java:170)
... 72 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javassist/util/proxy/ProxyObject
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at javassist.util.proxy.FactoryHelper.toClass(FactoryHelper.java:159)
... 73 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javassist.util.proxy.ProxyObject
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:506)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:410)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 81 more
163012 [btpool0-2 - /Gateway/zigbeedriver/app] WARN   org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer  - could not create proxy factory for:com.cartif.database.ApplicationField
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Javassist Enhancement failed: com.cartif.database.ApplicationField
at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.getProxyFactory(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:169)
at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistProxyFactory.postInstantiate(JavassistProxyFactory.java:65)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildProxyFactory(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:185)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.<init>(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:167)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.<init>(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:77)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor12.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:105)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructDefaultTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:133)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.<init>(EntityEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.java:80)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:322)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:485)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:133)
at org.hibernate.persister.PersisterFactory.createClassPersister(PersisterFactory.java:84)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:286)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1845)
at com.db.manager.DatabaseManager.createSession(DatabaseManager.java:74)
at com.db.manager.DatabaseManager.loadObject(DatabaseManager.java:95)
at com.cartif.database.User.loadUser(User.java:53)
at com.cartif.database.User.checkUser(User.java:57)
at com.cartif.zigbee.ZigbeeDriverImpl.checkUser(ZigbeeDriverImpl.java:124)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)
at org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.internal.aop.ServiceInvoker.doInvoke(ServiceInvoker.java:58)
at org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.internal.aop.ServiceInvoker.invoke(ServiceInvoker.java:62)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
at org.springframework.osgi.service.util.internal.aop.ServiceTCCLInterceptor.invokeUnprivileged(ServiceTCCLInterceptor.java:56)
at org.springframework.osgi.service.util.internal.aop.ServiceTCCLInterceptor.invoke(ServiceTCCLInterceptor.java:39)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
at org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.LocalBundleContextAdvice.invoke(LocalBundleContextAdvice.java:59)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
at $Proxy21.checkUser(Unknown Source)
at main.com.cartif.app.server.AppServiceImpl.getUser(AppServiceImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:569)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at main.com.cartif.app.server.AppServiceImpl.service(AppServiceImpl.java:33)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:362)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:726)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:206)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:320)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:842)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:648)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
at org.mortbay.thread.BoundedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(BoundedThreadPool.java:450)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: by java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javassist/util/proxy/ProxyObject
at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass(ProxyFactory.java:174)
at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.getProxyFactory(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:162)
... 71 more
Caused by: javassist.CannotCompileException: by java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javassist/util/proxy/ProxyObject
at javassist.util.proxy.FactoryHelper.toClass(FactoryHelper.java:167)
at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass(ProxyFactory.java:170)
... 72 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javassist/util/proxy/ProxyObject
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at javassist.util.proxy.FactoryHelper.toClass(FactoryHelper.java:159)
... 73 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javassist.util.proxy.ProxyObject
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:506)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:410)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 81 more
```

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: by java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javassist/util/proxy/ProxyObject This tells me that javassist cannot be accessed. How do you include this library into the project?

Comment: I add the library in folder 'lib' and I include a line in the manifest file like: Bundle-ClassPath:lib/javassist.jar

Comment: are you building a standalone application or a web-app?

Comment: It is a Web application in a OSGi context. Then I deploy war file like a bundle

Comment: if it's a web-app, you have to put your libraries into WEB-INF/lib folder. They will be picked up by your application.

Comment: It is a Web application but deployed as OSGi bundle. Then, in manifest file, it is specified where the libraries are. In my case, lib folder.

Comment: I don't have much experience in OSGI based web-apps, can't help you :) But you surely want to include this info in your question. Good luck

Answer (score 54, accepted):

When I ran into this error the fix was simple. I was simply missing a setter for a property. Make sure you define matching getters / setters for all your properties.

Comment: check the whole stack trace - it will tell you the name of the missing method.

Comment: I  was suffering from the same problem which is solved after reading your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Not the problem in my case. I have only two class variables and both have getters and setters.

Comment: I had a getter wich was not supposed to be persisted. Had to add @Transient to make it work.

Comment: Just surround your hibernate session factory initialization with a try and catch. The exception thrown should tell where the issue is.

Answer (score 71):

I was also facing the same issue.

Added the same dependency and it worked (like this):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javassist</groupId>
    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
    <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hi, can you please explain what javassit.jar do, why it fix this kind of problem and why i should add it to my project?

Comment: Hibernate uses Javassist proxies to help with lazy loading.

Answer (score 26):

I know its an old question and lots of answers are helpful but in my case, I faced with the same error unluckily the reason was different. (Spring boot version 2.0.5.RELEASE) If you are using

> IntelliJ idea 2018.1.5 or above  and you set JDK version as JDK 11

the same exception occurred. After updating the

> JDK version as 8

the error is gone.

Comment: Thanks. I was facing the same issue. An update to Spring Boot 2.1 did the trick, though, if that is an option.

Comment: Perfect thank you, I had the same problem with Spring Boot 2, changed the project back to v1.8 of the Java SDK and it solved the problem.

Comment: this was the answer for me

Answer (score 10):

I am using spring 3.0 and Hibernate 3.6 in my project. I ran into the same error just now. Googling this error message brought me to this page.

Funtik's comment on Jan 17 '12 at 8:49 helped me resolve the issue-

"This tells me that javassist cannot be accessed. How do you include this library into the project?"

So, I included java assist in my maven pom file as below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javassist</groupId>
    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
    <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
</dependency>
```

This resolved the issue for me. Thanks Funtik.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and resolved it adding this dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javassist</groupId>
    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
    <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
</dependency>
```

I am using hibernate 3.6 version.

Answer (score 3):

Add the following to your `pom.xml` and take out the dependency from `asm` jars from hibernate and add separate dependency to `asm` in a separate section. I did the same and it worked in one shot.

```
    <!-- Hibernate core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.7.ga</version>

   <exclusions>      
      <exclusion>
         <groupId>asm</groupId> 
           <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
         </exclusion>
      <exclusion>   
          <groupId>asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm-attrs</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>asm</groupId>
      <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
      <version>3.1</version>
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this post is old, but i ran in the same problem, and i solved it by simply changing my configuration from Java 11 down to Java 8.

Answer (score 2):

For me this was resolved by adding an explicit default constructor

```
public MyClassName (){}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javassist/util/proxy/ProxyObject at     java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
```

The issue is caused by "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError", so I think you should focus on this.

The direct solution is to add dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javassist</groupId>
    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
    <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
</dependency>
```

to your pom.xml.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same exception and I was excluding `javassist` because of its [issue with](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31189086/3328979) `powermock`. Then I was adding it again as below but it was not working:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
   <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
   <version>1.7.0</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
   <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
         <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
         <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
   <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
   <version>3.20.0-GA</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Finally I found out that I have to remove `<scope>test</scope>` from `javassist` dependency. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

same here with ***Jasper Reports Server (JRS) v7.2.0*** which is obviously **not compatible with Oracle JDK 11 (and likely OpenJDK 11)**, but the **distributed *Ora JDK 1.8.0_201* worked fine**.
This is also documented in the JRS community forum: https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/1141881/jasper-installation-community-version

Answer (score 1):

Check your Hibernate mapping file *.hbm.xml and check the class with which you are creating the getter and setter methods. Every property in the mapping file should exist as getters and setters in the populating class. Once you fix that the error is solved.

Also by reading the console, you can probably see the error mentioning a missing getter/setter.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Set the "long" type of id instead of java.lang.Integer. And add getters and setters to your fields.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is created due to  name="iSetPointId" make "i" capital and corresponding model class changes.

Comment: This answer could be added as a comment Im afraid.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a `isSomething()` boolean getter and got this error.

I resolved it by annotating the method with the JPA `@Transient` annotation and find a confirmation in an answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154622/why-does-jpa-have-a-transient-annotation), so telling the provider not to persist the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error even after adding no-arg constructor,Then I figured out that I was missing several JARs.I am posting this so that if anyone gets the error like I got, make sure you have added these JARs in your lib folder :

```
activation-1.0.2.jar
antlr-2.7.6.jar
aopalliance.jar
asm-1.5.3.jar
asm-attrs-1.5.3.jar
cglib-2.1_3.jar
commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
commons-collections-2.1.1.jar
commons-digester-1.8.jar
commons-email-1.0.jar
commons-fileupload-1.1.1.jar
commons-io-1.1.jar
commons-lang-2.5.jar
commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
dumbster-1.6.jar
ehcache-1.2.3.jar
ejb3-persistence-3.3.1.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.4.Final.jar
hibernate-core-4.2.8.Final.jar
icu4j-2.6.1.jar
javassist-3.4.GA.jar
javax.persistence_2.0.3.v201010191057.jar
javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.1.jar
jaxb-api-2.1.jar
jaxb-impl-2.1.3.jar
jaxen-1.1.1.jar
jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar
jdom-1.0.jar
jstl-1.2.jar
jta-1.1.jar
lucene-core-2.3.2.jar
lucene-highlighter-2.0.0.jar
mail-1.4.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar
org.springframework.orm.jar
slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.5.6.jar
spring-aop-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-aspects-4.0.0.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-build-src-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-framework-bom-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-jdbc-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-orm-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
stax-api-1.0-2.jar
validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar
xalan-2.6.0.jar
xercesImpl-2.6.2.jar
xml-apis-1.3.02.jar
xmlParserAPIs-2.6.2.jar
xom-1.0.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and after going over a lot on stack overflow and spending time on the jar dependencies, I figured out that in my case, I had two sets of asm.jar. I removed one of them and it worked fine...

Answer (score 0):

In my case has helped to exclude javax.transaction.jta dependency from hibernate:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.7.ga</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
      <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do check Hibernate Property Name and Id Name also.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a Kotlin class with some fields which were not open so the generated Java 
 setters and getters would be final. Solved it by adding `open` keyword to each field.

Before:

```
open class User(
    var id: String = "",
    var email: String = ""
)
```

After:

```
open class User(
    open var id: String = "",
    open var email: String = ""
)
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue was due to version conflict. 
I resolved this issue by excluding byte-buddy dependency from springfox

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
  <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
  <version>2.7.0</version>
  <exclusions>
  <exclusion>
    <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
    <artifactId>byte-buddy</artifactId>
  </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
  <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
  <version>2.7.0</version>
  <exclusions>
  <exclusion>
    <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
    <artifactId>byte-buddy</artifactId>
  </exclusion>
</exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Years later, the problem came back, after i changed my machine to M1 apple Chip.

After some research i found my answer in this google group:https://groups.google.com/g/repo-discuss/c/v3EHHdjDhiU

`tldr:` I needed to add `--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED` as a VM option to my local environment. After this, all worked fine again.