# PowerMock Java 8 and Comparator.comparing issue

Tags: java, java-8, powermock

I have to sort my `List` of `Foo` objects by its `name`.

I have wrote a method like this (class: `FooUtils`):

```
private void sortByName(List<Foo> foos) {
    foos.sort(Comparator.comparing(Foo::getName));
}
```

I'm using a `PowerMock` to test a private method. Test looks like this:

```
@Test
public void sortByName(){
    List<Foo> unsortedFoos = //prepare unsorted list of foos
    List<Foo> expectedFoos = //prepare expected, sorted list of foos

    Whitebox.invokeMethod(FooUtils, "sortByName", unsortedFoos );
    Assert.assertEquals(expectedFoos, unsortedFoos);
}
```

However test cause error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to transform class with name pl.sample.Foo. Reason: javassist.bytecode.InterfaceMethodrefInfo cannot be cast to javassist.bytecode.MethodrefInfo

at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadMockClass(MockClassLoader.java:266)
at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadModifiedClass(MockClassLoader.java:180)
at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:68)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:340)
at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:114)
at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125)
at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseSig(AnnotationParser.java:439)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassValue(AnnotationParser.java:420)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(AnnotationParser.java:724)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(AnnotationParser.java:531)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:355)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:286)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:120)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:72)
at java.lang.Class.createAnnotationData(Class.java:3508)
at java.lang.Class.annotationData(Class.java:3497)
at java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Class.java:3402)
at org.junit.internal.MethodSorter.getDeclaredMethods(MethodSorter.java:52)
at org.junit.internal.runners.TestClass.getAnnotatedMethods(TestClass.java:45)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodValidator.validateTestMethods(MethodValidator.java:71)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodValidator.validateStaticMethods(MethodValidator.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodValidator.validateMethodsForDefaultRunner(MethodValidator.java:50)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.validate(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:108)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.<init>(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:70)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.<init>(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:42)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit49RunnerDelegateImpl.<init>(PowerMockJUnit49RunnerDelegateImpl.java:25)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:156)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:40)
at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.createTestDelegators(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:244)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.<init>(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:61)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.<init>(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:32)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.<init>(PowerMockRunner.java:34)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:29)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:21)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:26)
at org.junit.internal.requests.FilterRequest.getRunner(FilterRequest.java:31)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:49)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:237)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: javassist.bytecode.InterfaceMethodrefInfo cannot be cast to javassist.bytecode.MethodrefInfo
at javassist.bytecode.ConstPool.getMethodrefType(ConstPool.java:452)
at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.Tracer.doInvokeMethod(Tracer.java:800)
at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.Tracer.doOpcode148_201(Tracer.java:597)
at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.Tracer.doOpcode(Tracer.java:81)
at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.MapMaker.make(MapMaker.java:187)
at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.MapMaker.make(MapMaker.java:199)
at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.MapMaker.make(MapMaker.java:164)
at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.MapMaker.make(MapMaker.java:108)
at javassist.bytecode.MethodInfo.rebuildStackMap(MethodInfo.java:423)
at javassist.bytecode.MethodInfo.rebuildStackMapIf6(MethodInfo.java:405)
at javassist.CtBehavior.insertBefore(CtBehavior.java:768)
at javassist.CtBehavior.insertBefore(CtBehavior.java:734)
at org.powermock.core.transformers.impl.MainMockTransformer.modifyMethod(MainMockTransformer.java:197)
at org.powermock.core.transformers.impl.MainMockTransformer.allowMockingOfStaticAndFinalAndNativeMethods(MainMockTransformer.java:133)
at org.powermock.core.transformers.impl.MainMockTransformer.transform(MainMockTransformer.java:65)
at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadMockClass(MockClassLoader.java:251)
... 58 more
```

What is more, when I replace a `Comparator.comparing(Foo::getName)` with a
`(u1, u2) -> u1.getName().compareTo(u2.getName())` then test pass with success.

I have read a this thread: [PowerMock and Java 8 issue: InterfaceMethodrefInfo cannot be cast to MethodrefInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31189086/powermock-and-java-8-issue-interfacemethodrefinfo-cannot-be-cast-to-methodrefin)

When I will exclude `javassist` and add it as a dependency, test pass but spring boot application fails to start with error:

```
2017-02-20 09:23:20,920 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1 ] SpringApplication - Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javassist/bytecode/ClassFile
```

So it is not a solution for me.

So my question is, is there any other solution, or maybe i need to use just old way to sort list without `Comparator.comparing()`?

Comment: You need to exclude one version of javaasist but include newer, where bug with static interface methods is fixed.

Comment: I have tried this already as I mentioned "When I will exclude javassist and add it as a dependency". leads to `BeanCreationException` then