# Spring-boot + Hibernate + JPA with transient fields

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, netbeans

This is my first question, but I have been looking for a solution for 2 days, with no success.
In my project, I have a `User` entity with a transient property:

```
@Transient
@JsonProperty
private List<String> files;
```

I have no setter, and getter is:

```
public List<String> getFiles() {
    /* Call one static method */
}
```

Executing the application with NetBeans in debug, works fine, and from javascript, I can get the getFiles results, using `user.fotos`.  But when I generate .jar file, and I execute the application with command `java -jar app.jar`, by calling one Rest function that must return one `User` object, I get this exception:

```
2015-10-28 14:39:35.963  WARN 27836 --- [nio-7777-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failed to write HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write content: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: com.pfc.soriano.wsdbmodel.entity.User["files"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: com.pfc.soriano.wsdbmodel.entity.User["files"])
2015-10-28 14:39:35.963  WARN 27836 --- [nio-7777-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Handler execution resulted in exception: Could not write content: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: com.pfc.soriano.wsdbmodel.entity.User["files"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: com.pfc.soriano.wsdbmodel.entity.User["files"])
```

My question is: What is Netbeans doing different from command line java -jar, which makes it work fine?

Comment: so you get an NPE, and ? only you know what line of what code that is ...

Comment: What do you need to know, Neil?  From method getFiles(), I'm calling one static method:
`public static Collection<String> getImages(String prefix, String path) {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        File directorio = new File(path);
        TruequeFiltro filtro = new TruequeFiltro(prefix);
        for (File file : directorio.listFiles(filtro)) {
            result.add(file.getName());
        }
        return result;
    }`

Comment: You have an NPE, so work out which line, then work out WHAT is null, then fix it.

Comment: I don't need to do anything in order to get NPE.  I have one UserController, with `@Autowired UserDao userDao;` and this method: `    @RequestMapping(value = "findById", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public User findById(@Param("id") Long id) {
        return userDao.findOne(id);
    }
`.
UserDao is defined as: `@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "users", itemResourceRel = "users")
public interface UserDao extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
`
When I call from javascript with ajax the method findById, I obtain the exception that appears in my first comment.

Comment: If I run the application with netbeans, everything works fine.  If I run the application with `java -jar app.jar` command, nothing works.  And if I delete the transient field `files` and getter and setter, everything works fine using netbeans or command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to find some documentation more, I found this: [JPA Transient Annotation and JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25743802/5113951)

Thanks to Damien, finally I have my project working fine:
Main Application.java:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    /* Here we register the Hibernate4Module into an ObjectMapper, then set this custom-configured ObjectMapper
     * to the MessageConverter and return it to be added to the HttpMessageConverters of our application*/
    public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jacksonMessageConverter() {
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter messageConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Hibernate4Module hm = new Hibernate4Module();
        hm.disable(Hibernate4Module.Feature.USE_TRANSIENT_ANNOTATION);
        mapper.registerModule(hm);

        messageConverter.setObjectMapper(mapper);
        return messageConverter;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(jacksonMessageConverter());
        super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

User entity Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;
    @Transient
    Collection<String> files;

    public Long getId() {
        files = Utils.getImages("" + id, "src/main/webapp/user/");
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Collection<String> getFiles() {
        return files;
    }

    public void setFiles(Collection<String> files) {
        this.files = files;
    }
}
```

UserDAO interface:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "users", itemResourceRel = "users")
public interface UserDAO extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

}
```

UserController:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "user")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    UserDAO userDAO;

    @RequestMapping(value = "findById", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public User findById(@Param("id") Long id) {
        return userDAO.findOne(id);
    }
}
```

Javascript function:

```
function loadUser(id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: serviceBaseUrl + "user/findById",
        data: {id: id},
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            if(data) {
                alert(data.files);
                /* DO SOMETHING ELSE */
            }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(jqXHR.responseJSON.message);
        }
    });
}
```

The result is that javascript show me an alert with the file names that exists on the server.