# JSON: @Transient field not serializing

Tags: json, spring, jackson

I have a domain class Loan.java with a field which is not persisted:

```
@JsonInclude()
@Transient
private LoanRating loanRating;

/* (Public) Getters and setters for that field are available as well */
```

However, the field does not get serialized - I don't see it on Frontend. I'm doing the serialization with Jackson.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

If you need more information, please tell me and I'll post additional code :)

Comment: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25714960/3094731) answer please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JPA Transient Annotation and JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25713884/jpa-transient-annotation-and-json)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks for your answers!
The comment of @Abdullah Khan pointed me to the correct (and probably easiest) solution.

I solved it with adding the @JsonSerialize annotation:

```
@Transient
@JsonSerialize
private LoanRating loanRating;
```

Thanks all for your help :)

Answer (score 3):

You can simply define a getter with an JsonProperty annotation like this :

```
@JsonProperty("LoanRating")
public String getLoanRatingSer() {
    return this.loanRating;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this simple solution. This worked for me.