# Spring Data Rest PATCH requests do not fill transient properties not backed by a field

Tags: spring, spring-data-rest, transient, http-patch

I want to implement a PATCH-Requese on an entity 'User' for changing the password with an additional transient property 'oldpassword' to compare it in the EventHandler.

The POST- and the PUT-request fill the property.

The PATCH-request doesn't: 'oldpassword' is null.

**I'm using**

- spring-boot-starter-parent
- spring-boot-starter-data-rest (2.1.6)
- spring-boot-starter-web (2.1.6)
- spring-boot-starter-data-jpa (2.1.6)
- spring-data-jpa 2.1.9
- spring-data-rest 3.1.9
- spring-security 5.1.5 (presumably irrelevant)

**I tried**

- the annotation @JsonProperty("oldpassword") (even though POST and PUT work).
- the annotation @JsonDeserialize ([JSON: @Transient field not seralizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46683141/json-transient-field-not-seralizing))
- to configure Jackson to disable the check for @Transient annotations ([JPA Transient Annotation and JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25713884/jpa-transient-annotation-and-json/25743802#25743802#))
- @JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = Visibility.ANY) as class decorator

**The simplified code is:**

The entity 'User'

```java
@Entity
public class User implements UserDetails, Serializable {

    [...]

    @NotNull
    String password;

    @Transient
    String newpassword;

    @Transient
    String oldpassword;


    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.newpassword = password;
    }

    public void setOldpassword(String oldpassword) {
        this.oldpassword = oldpassword;
    }

    [...]



}
```

The Repository

```java
@RepositoryRestResource(exported = true)
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
}
```

PATCH-Request (

```
      HTTP Method = PATCH
      Request URI = /api/users/2
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json;charset=UTF-8", Authorization:"Basic aXJ0Z2VuZGFhczpFaW4gcGFzc3dvcmQ="]
             Body = {
    "username": "myusername",
    "password": "mynewpassword",
    "oldpassword": "theoldone"
}
```

The EventHandler

```java
@Component
@RepositoryEventHandler(User.class)
public class UserEventHandler {

    @HandleBeforeSave
    public void printdata(User p) {
        /* returns the new password*/
        System.out.println("newpassword" + p.newpassword);

        /* returns null (if it's a PATCH-request) */
        System.out.println("oldpassword" + p.oldpassword);

        /* returns the old persisted password */
        System.out.println("password" + p.password);
    }

}
```

**The transient property 'newpassword' works**, since I use the setter of the persisted property 'password'.

Comment: Reported as bug to SDR. @Transient annotation won't deserialize fields on MongoRepository PATCH requests [DATAREST-1524]. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/issues/1881

Comment: DATAREST-1524 - Fix deserialization of transient fiels with setters. #381. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/pull/381

Comment: Great, thanks for the information. I dropped the approach. But  it is nice to know.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to create a change-password feature. It won't work this way. Create a unique controller method for it.

It's not a standard REST request anyway.