# How to save a list in an object using Java?

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, pojo

Before saving
[image]

After saving
[image]

```
@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class Notification {


  @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long notificationId;
    private Long businessId;
    private String actionBy;
    private String date;
    private String notification;
    public ArrayList<UserNotification> user;

  //constructor here

  //getters setters here
}
```

and UserNotification.java is

```
public class UserNotification {
private Long id;
private String user;
private String notifCount;
//getters setters here
}
```

I don't know why is it returning null. At what point I made a mistake?

EDIT:

```
 var usersObj=[];
        BusinessRoleService.getByBusinessId($sessionStorage.businessRole.business).then(function(response){
            if(response.status==200){
                for(var x=0;x<response.data.length;x++){
                    usersObj.push({id: x, user: response.data[x].userId, notifCount: $scope.notification});
                }


            }
        });

        var obj = {
            "businessId": businessId,
            "actionBy": user,
            "date": date,
            "notification": user+" "+action,
            "user": usersObj
        }
```

then I will pass the obj to my service to save

This is what my database looks like after saving

[image]

Comment: Your array name is `user`, but it should be `users`, and look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2154640/5686835)

Comment: In your IndexController change list name users to user

Comment: Both Javascript and java object names should be matched

Comment: Please check the post again. It saves now but empty

Comment: Update your question and provide the full Notification and UserNotification class definitions (with every annotation)

Comment: @RogerC done please check again

Comment: Why is UserNotification not an @Entity? Also you need to tell JPA what kind of relationship ties Notification to UserNotification. My guess is there's a bunch of annotations missing on both classes. Read this :https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany

Comment: @Mark https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25713884/jpa-transient-annotation-and-json/25743802 check that question

Comment: I don't want to have a table UserNotification. I just want Notification table only

Comment: How are you going to store a list of UserNotification in your Notification table? Give us your table structure please.

Comment: @RogerC please check the post again

Comment: You need to provide the structure of the Notification table. In what kind of field are you storing your `user` property? Otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: @RogerC I used JPA so it generated on its own. As I checked my database it is TINYBLOB

Answer (score 2):

In your `Notification` Java object, the `user` property has the `@Transient` annotation. Which means it won't be persisted.

So, the property is null in the response of your controller.

As other have said, you also have a difference in your JavaScript and Java structure. In your Notification java object, your list should be named `users`

**After your last edit :**

Why is `UserNotification` not an `@Entity`? Also you need to tell JPA what kind of relationship ties `Notification` to `UserNotification`. My guess is there's a bunch of annotations missing on both classes. Read this :https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany

Comment: what shall I do then?

Comment: Remove @Transient

Comment: In your IndexController change list name users to user

Comment: it is still null

Comment: @Lakshman damn didn't notice that one. it saves now but it is empty

Comment: Please check the post again. It saves now but empty

Comment: @Mark see this question, it may be helpful  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25713884/jpa-transient-annotation-and-json/25743802

Comment: I added entity but it still don't save

Comment: where are you saving this object, did you checked in your database?

Comment: the second image was returned and save like that. I am saving it in Notification table

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169756/discussion-between-mark-and-lakshman).