# Exclude Field in Class from JPA

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I have an entity in JPA. I recently added a field to my entity. I do not want this field to be persisted. However, Eclipselink is complaining about it not being in the table (which it obviously isnt).

How can I exclude this class from be looked at by JPA. Please note that this field cannot be transient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add JPA's [@Transient](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Transient.html). 
Field annotated with `Transient` will not be persisted.

Comment: Awesome, will this still allow the field to be serialized too?

Comment: Great, just implemented it, worked like a charm. I will accept this in a few min

Answer (score 0):

One option is adding [@Transient](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Transient.html) annotation if on the other hand you use [transient keyword](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Keywords/transient) that means the field won't be serialized.
More on [Why does JPA have a @Transient annotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154622/why-does-jpa-have-a-transient-annotation)

Comment: "Please note that this field cannot be transient."