# Non-persisting fields: JPA '@Transient' vs Java SE 7 'transient'

Tags: java, jpa, entity, transient

Which one to use for skipping field persisting in an Entity?

> **@Transient** is used as part of JPA to ignore a field from persisting
>
> The **transient** keyword in Java is used to indicate that a field should
>   not be serialized and persisted (Specification of Java SE 7 Edition)

I checked the both, and for the both no column is generated in the database :

**The entity :**

```
@Entity
public class Person implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String forname;

    @Transient
    private String nickName;

    private transient String pseudo;
```

**The generated table :**

[image]

Comment: "transient" is nothing to do with persistence ... it is to prevent serialisation and nothing else. "persistence" != "serialisation"

Answer (score 0):

You should use transient, according to the specification

Comment: @Transient is used to persisting, and not for a serialization this is that i want to say when talk about specification, you ask for serialization.

Comment: Well @Trigon219, but I you said in the attached image, I'm looking for persistence in database... And both gave the same result.. no column is generated for corresponding fields...

Comment: Ok so, if you want the field don`t be persist, then use @Transient even this is more related with the JPA framework, that is you are using.

Comment: Any detailed reason for that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154622/why-does-jpa-have-a-transient-annotation