# Null in response

Tags: java, spring, rest

When I do

```
GET /survey/1
```

I get this response, althought there are questions and answers in my database:

```
{
  "surveyId": 1,
  "name": "Example",
  "questions": null,
  "answers": null
}
```

Why I get null in 'questions' and 'answers'? How could I fix it?

SurveyRepository:

```
public interface SurveyRepository extends CrudRepository<Survey, Integer> { }
```

Survey's model class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "survey")
public class Survey {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "surveyId")
    private Integer surveyId;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Transient
    private List<String> questions;

    @Transient
    private List<String> answers;

    public Survey() { }

    public Survey(Integer surveyId, String name) {
        this.surveyId = surveyId;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getSurveyId() {
        return surveyId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public List<String> getQuestions() {
        return questions;
    }

    public List<String> getAnswers() {
        return answers;
    }

    public void setSurveyId(Integer surveyId) {
        this.surveyId = surveyId;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setQuestions(List<String> questions) {
        this.questions = questions;
    }

    public void setAnswers(List<String> answers) {
        this.answers = answers;
    }
}
```

Survey's controller class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/survey")
public class SurveyController {

    @Autowired
    private SurveyRepository surveyRepo;

    @Autowired
    private AnswerRepository answerRepo;

    @Autowired
    private QuestionRepository questionRepo;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/{id}")
    public Survey getSurveyById(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
        return surveyRepo.findOne(id);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String create(@RequestBody Survey survey) {
        surveyRepo.save(survey);
        return "Survey created";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Iterable<Survey> getAllSurveys() {
        return surveyRepo.findAll();
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.DELETE, value = "/{id}")
    public String delete(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
        surveyRepo.delete(id);
        return "Survey deleted";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, value = "/{id}")
    public String update(@PathVariable("id") int id, @RequestBody Survey survey) {
        Survey update = surveyRepo.findOne(id);

        update.setName(survey.getName());
        update.setQuestions(survey.getQuestions());

        surveyRepo.save(update);
        return "Survey updated";
    }

}
```

Answer model class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "answer")
public class Answer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "answerId")
    private Integer answerId;

    @Column(name = "answer", nullable = false)
    private String answer;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "questionId", nullable = false)
    private Question questionId;

    public Answer() { }

    public Answer(Integer answerId, String answer, Question questionId) {
        this.answerId = answerId;
        this.answer = answer;
        this.questionId = questionId;
    }

    public Integer getAnswerId() {
        return answerId;
    }

    public String getAnswer() {
        return answer;
    }

    public Question getQuestionId() {
        return questionId;
    }

    public void setAnswerId(Integer answerId) {
        this.answerId = answerId;
    }

    public void setAnswer(String answer) {
        this.answer = answer;
    }

    public void setQuestionId(Question questionId) {
        this.questionId = questionId;
    }

}
```

Question model class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "question")
public class Question {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "questionId")
    private Integer questionId;

    @Column(name = "question", nullable = false)
    private String question;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "surveyId", nullable = false)
    private Survey surveyId;

    @Transient
    private List<String> answers;

    public Question() { }

    public Question(Integer questionId, String question, Survey surveyId) {
        this.questionId = questionId;
        this.question = question;
        this.surveyId = surveyId;
    }

    public Integer getQuestionId() {
        return questionId;
    }

    public String getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }

    public Survey getSurveyId() {
        return surveyId;
    }

    public void setQuestionId(Integer questionId) {
        this.questionId = questionId;
    }

    public void setQuestion(String question) {
        this.question = question;
    }

    public void setSurveyId(Survey surveyId) {
        this.surveyId = surveyId;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You marked them as `@Transient` which, depending on which one you're using either means it won't be serialized, or won't be stored in the database. See [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154622/why-does-jpa-have-a-transient-annotation) Also, unrelated you should probably use `@ElementCollection(targetClass = String.class)` on those `Lists`

Answer (score 0):

You no have a relationship with your Survey and Questions.

> A OneToMany relationship in Java is where the source object has an
>   attribute that stores a collection of target objects and if those
>   target objects had the inverse relationship back to the source object
>   it would be a ManyToOne relationship. All relationships in Java and
>   JPA are unidirectional, in that if a source object references a target
>   object there is no guarantee that the target object also has a
>   relationship to the source object. This is different than a relational
>   database, in which relationships are defined through foreign keys and
>   querying such that the inverse query always exists.
>
> JPA also defines a ManyToMany relationship, which is similar to a
>   OneToMany relationship except that the inverse relationship (if it
>   were defined) is a ManyToMany relationship. The main difference
>   between a OneToMany and a ManyToMany relationship in JPA is that a
>   ManyToMany always makes use of an intermediate relational join table
>   to store the relationship, whereas a OneToMany can either use a join
>   table, or a foreign key in target object's table referencing the
>   source object table's primary key. If the OneToMany uses a foreign key
>   in the target object's table JPA requires that the relationship be
>   bi-directional (inverse ManyToOne relationship must be defined in the
>   target object), and the source object must use the mappedBy attribute
>   to define the mapping.

Read More to [JPA Persistence](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany)  and this [tutorial Spring](https://hellokoding.com/jpa-one-to-many-relationship-mapping-example-with-spring-boot-maven-and-mysql/)

Comment: I edited my post and added Question and Answer model classes - I use @ManyToOne annotations there.