# How to generate UUID using spring annotations

Tags: spring, hibernate, annotations, uuid

I want to generate UUID in spring controller.
I am new to this and I was exploring following

```
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
private String corrId;
```

I do not want to associate this uuid with any database column/field but want it to be unique(I am not sure if this is possible)

When I try to print value of String 'corrId', it always gives me null

I have also tried but value of corrId is still null

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
private String corrId;
```

Am I doing something wrong here or my approach is completely wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can simply define field this way:

```
@Transient
private UUID corrId = UUID.randomUUID();
```

Please read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513573/how-good-is-javas-uuid-randomuuid) about UUID.randomUUID() and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154622/why-does-jpa-have-a-transient-annotation) about @Transient.

Comment: I get this error Incorrect string value: '\xFD\xB3\xEC\xBA\x0B\xB1...' for column