# What is the lifetime of the JPA @Transient annotated field

Tags: jpa, transient

I am having a difficult time trying to understand the Transient annotation of JPA. I assume the fields noted with Transient annotation will be stored in a local cache and not persisted in DB. I basically like to know when will it be cleaned up from the local cache?
I am using this for a table to store its intermittent status and I use this value in a method that is returned after I call an external service. Is this an appropriate use case? If so, what will be the life time of such a transient field?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
@Entity
class Sample {
  @Transient 
  String fieldOne;

  transient String otherField;
}
```

`fieldOne` is not transient (has not `transient` keyword), so is serialised (to/from cache, network, file or other sources). But JPA will not store it in database, because annotation denies.

`otherField` is not seriazable, has `transient` keyword (i.e. after getting from cache engine, or network can/will be null), but is pesissted in JPA database with default behaviour

This is not academic discussion, sometimes it is useable. Usually values computed from others, or hashed /encrypted /hidden fields.

Comment: Thanks for the response. In this example, what will be the lifetime of fieldOne once it is assigned a value?

Comment: this is "normal" Java field, notching change, and "only" not stored in database. Annotation has meaning only (i hope) for JPA framework. So when in the futore new instance will be born by reanging from bd, will be null

Comment: This answer is simply wrong. JPA will **not** persist fields that are marked `transient` either.  For anyone reading this question, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154622/why-does-jpa-have-a-transient-annotation for a more detailed explanation