# Hibernate method that starts with "is", but isn't a getter

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, getter

I'm modeling an entity with hibernate. I'm using the [JavaFX Property Pattern](http://svanimpe.be/blog/properties-jpa).

I'm using `PROPERTY` access so Hibernate is looking at my methods for configuration.

My problem is the word "Issue" starts with "is" and so it seems that Hibernate thinks my property method is a getter for a boolean—something like `isOpen()`.

It throws the following error when I try set up a `SessionFactory`:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty, at table: Remediations, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(sueDetailProperty)]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:456)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:423)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:226)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:597)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:265)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:329)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:459)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:710)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)
    at TestManyToManyWithExtraColumns.setUpSessionFactory(TestManyToManyWithExtraColumns.java:106)
    at TestManyToManyWithExtraColumns.<clinit>(TestManyToManyWithExtraColumns.java:16)
```

Here's a watered down version to show the problem:

```
@Entity
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
public class MyEntity{
    ...

    @Column(name = "detail_id")
    public IssueDetail getIssueDetail() {
        return issueDetail.get();
    }

    public void setIssueDetail(IssueDetail issueDetail) {
        this.issueDetail.set(issueDetail);
    }

    // throws error:
    // "Could not determine type for: javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty,
    // at table: Remediations, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(sueDetailProperty)]"
                                         |
    public ObjectProperty<IssueDetail> issueDetailProperty() {
        return issueDetail.getOrCreateProperty();
    } 
}
```

**How do I get Hibernate to stop thinking my method is a getter (besides changing the method name?)**

Comment: Did you test with a different name and works?

Comment: Mark it `@Transient`.

Comment: @KESO, it does work with a different name, but I'm sure you'll agree that it's important to stick to convention, if possible.

Comment: @teppic, thanks, `@Transient` seems to work. If you want to leave an answer explaining why it works, maybe with some sources, I think that might be the right answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does JPA have a @Transient annotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154622/why-does-jpa-have-a-transient-annotation)

Comment: @teppic, I don't think it's a duplicate. [_That question_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154622/why-does-jpa-have-a-transient-annotation) is about the difference between Java's `transient` keyword and JPA's `@Transient` annotation. _This question_ describes a problem where `@Transient` just happens to be the solution. Would you agree?