# Spring Data and Redis - serializing transient fields

Tags: java, redis, spring-data

I am using Redis as my database with Spring data, with no custom value or hash value serializer. I assume the standrad JdkSerializationRedisSerializer should be used then for objects serialization. 
It looks like transient fields of some objects are serialized to the database.

Transient field modifier, transient method annotations, @JsonIgnore properties - all of them don't seem to affect the serialization of the field.

How can I overcome this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is two years too late for poor Matt, but we recently ran into this issue, as well.  What *seems* to work is:

1. Set a serialization ID on the Java class. Eclipse and IntelliJ will both generate one for you.  -1 doesn't seem to work.
2. Use the transient Java modifier, not the Spring @Transient tag.

:

```
public class CachedValues implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -914745617137492359L;
    private Long id;
    private transient String nonRedisField;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and whilst I initially had marked the field as transient, which I believed would make it transient ;-) it didnt when it came to spring data redis.

What worked for me was annotating the field:

```
    ...
    import org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient;
    ...
    @Transient
    private ReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
```

the pojo did not have to implement Serializable and the field did not have to marked as transient. I guess its still good Java practice to do this, but it was not a requirement.

Comment: Having posted the above, I have since read this answer which might explain it a bit better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35641998/1279002

Answer (score 0):

We had a same issue, I used transient(java keyword) and `org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient` annotation as well but it did not work, however using `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore` did the trick.

It actually depends on how the underline redis is implemented and what serializer or deserializer it uses.