# Boolean function in Java entity class causing JSON NullPointerException

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I'm currently working on a Spring Boot backend application with JPA and I encountered a peculiar error. After setting up the columns in the entity file, we have a public function that returns a boolean based on whether something is active or not.

```
    public boolean isPartnerActive() {
        return this.status.getPartnerStatus().contentEquals("A");
    }
```

This function is only meant to be used as boolean values in our controller, but when we try running our backend application to test a "Post" call in the Partner controller, we encounter a `NullPointerError` saying we have null field called `partneractive`. During our debugging, we changed the function name to `isActive` and the same error occurred, but the null field this time is `active`.

It seems as though this is notation issue with `is` as the starting letters for a function, because as soon as we changed the function name or added the `@JsonIgnore` annotation to the function, we were able to make the post call.

I'm not necessarily looking for a solution to this issue; I just want to understand why this situation happens.

Answer (score 0):

Annotate the `isPartnerActive()` method in your entity as `@Transient` and the exception will go away.

How it works, follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2154640/1156233)