# How to solve the targeting an unmapped class error from hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping

I'm trying to map 2 entities (Course and Student), I have 2 Java classes and 2 MySQL tables, having a `ManyToMany` relationship. I created the junction table and java class Enrolment (as I want extra information such as the date of enrolment of a student to a course).

I'm trying to insert data using hibernate in this Enrolments table in the MySQL but I keep getting errors. Here are my POJO classes:

Course class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "course")
public class Course {


private int id;

@Column(name = "chapter_id")
private int chapterId;;

@Column(name = "name")
private String title;   

@Column(name = "teacher_user_id")
private int teacherId;

 @OneToMany(targetEntity=Enrolment.class, mappedBy="course", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
// @JoinTable(name = "enrolment",
         //   joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "course_id"),
         //   inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_user_id"))
private List<Enrolment> enrolments = new ArrayList<Enrolment>();

public Course(){}

public Course(int id, int chapterId, String title, int teacherId) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.chapterId = chapterId;
    this.title = title;
    this.teacherId = teacherId;
}


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
public int getId() {
    return id;
}


public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}


public int getChapterId() {
    return chapterId;
}


public void setChapterId(int chapterId) {
    this.chapterId = chapterId;
}


public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}


public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}


public int getTeacherId() {
    return teacherId;
}


public void setTeacherId(int teacherId) {
    this.teacherId = teacherId;
}

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "course")
public List<Enrolment> getEnrolments() {
    return enrolments;
}

public void setEnrolments(List<Enrolment> courses) {
    this.enrolments = courses;
}

public void addEnrolment(Enrolment enrolment) {
    this.enrolments.add(enrolment);
}
}
```

Student class (this class is inherited from User parent class, I will attach User Class down below as well. In the database there are different tables as well: User and then Student and Teacher that inherit User parent entity):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "user_id")
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
public class Student extends User  {

private int grade;


private List<Enrolment> enrolments = new ArrayList<Enrolment>();

public Student(){} 

public Student(String fname, String lname, String email, String password, String address, String phone,
        int userType, int grade, boolean isAdmin) 
{
    super(fname, lname, email, password, address, phone, userType, isAdmin);

    this.grade=grade;

}

public int getGrade() {
    return grade;
}

public void setGrade(int grade) {
    this.grade = grade;
}


public void setEnrolments(List<Enrolment> courses) {
    this.enrolments = courses;
}

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "student")
public List<Enrolment> getEnrolments() {
    return enrolments;
}

public void addCourse(Enrolment course) {
    this.enrolments.add(course);
}

public void addEnrolment(Enrolment enrolment) {
    this.enrolments.add(enrolment);
}
```

}

User Class:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;
private String firstname;
private String lastname;
private String email;
private String password;
private String address;
private String phone;

@Column(name = "user_type_id")
private int userType;

@Column(name = "is_admin")
private boolean isAdmin;


public User(String fname, String lname, String email, String password, String address, String phone,
        int userType, boolean isAdmin) {
    //super();

    this.firstname = fname;
    this.lastname = lname;
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
    this.address = address;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.userType = userType;
    this.isAdmin = isAdmin;
}

public User() {}
//getters & setters
```

And finally this is the Enrolment class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "enrolment")
public class Enrolment {


private int id;
private Student user;
private Course course;

@Column(name = "enrolment_date")
private Date enrolmentDate;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}


@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "student_user_id")
public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(Student user) {
    this.user = user;
}

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "course_id")
public Course getCourse() {
    return course;
}

public void setCourse(Course course) {
    this.course = course;
}

public Date getEnrolmentDate() {
    return enrolmentDate;
}

public void setEnrolmentDate(Date enrolmentDate) {
    this.enrolmentDate = enrolmentDate;
}
```

So I'm trying to read a course and a student from database and insert the information in this Enrolment table but it gives errors since trying to read a Course. Here is the DAO method:

```
 @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Transactional
public List<Course> getCoursesOfChapter(int chapterId) {


    Configuration con = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").addAnnotatedClass(Course.class);
    SessionFactory sf = con.buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = sf.openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();


    Query query = session.createQuery("from Course where chapter_id = :chapterId");
      query.setParameter("chapterId",chapterId);

     // List list = query.list();

        tx.commit();
      return (List<Course>) query.list();
```

It throws the error at the session factory building:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: models.Course.enrolments[models.Enrolment]
at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindManyToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1255)
at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:808)
at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:733)
at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:54)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1696)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1664)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:287)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:84)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:474)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:85)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:689)
at dao.CourseDAO.getCourse(CourseDAO.java:52)
at webapp.Main.main(Main.java:132)
```

Finally, this is my call:

```
CourseDAO cdao = new CourseDAO();

Course course = cdao.getCourse(1);
```

I've tried playing with the annotations, make them ManyToMany instead of ManyToOne. I tried to map the User class instead of Student but still didn't work. I tried to make it without the junction class of Enrolment and just generate it without having an actual class for it but still didn't work (as I had to work with 2 session.save() methods one after the other which also gave some error that I couldn't solve). Probably it's a small thing that I'm missing here but I just can't figure it out, sorry for too long code but I really need to solve it fast. If you read through here, I really thank you!

So my question is: Am I missing something here from these mappings and annotations or I should change the structure of my classes?

Answer (score 1):

Boiling down a problem to the bare minimum greatly helps others help you. Here are simpler versions of your student, course and enrollment classes that can be unit tested easily. The many-to-many association between course and student is separated into two many-to-one associations from Enrollment. Note that the associations are bidirectional and that the *many* side is mapped by the *one* side. Student cascades persistence operations to Enrollment, which reflects how schools normally work: students enroll in courses, not the other way around.

**Course.java**

```
@Entity
public class Course {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String title;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "course")
    private List<Enrollment> enrollments;

    Course() {
    }

    Course(String title) {
        this.title = title;
        this.enrollments = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    void add(Enrollment enrollment) {
        enrollments.add(enrollment);
    }

    Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    List<Enrollment> getEnrollments() {
        return enrollments;
    }
}
```

**Student.java**

```
@Entity
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student", cascade = ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Enrollment> enrollments;

    Student() {
    }

    Student(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.enrollments = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    void enroll(Course course) {
        enrollments.add(new Enrollment(course, this));
    }
}
```

**Enrollment.java**

```
@Entity
public class Enrollment {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Course course;

    @ManyToOne
    private Student student;

    Enrollment() {
    }

    Enrollment(Course course, Student student) {
        this.course = course;
        this.student = student;
        course.add(this);
    }
}
```

The test case below checks that the entities are mapped and associated correctly. You can run it with Spring Boot.

**SchoolTest.java**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@Transactional
public class SchoolTest {

    @Autowired
    private CourseRepository courseRepository;
    @Autowired
    private StudentRepository studentRepository;

    @Test
    public void run() {
        Course course = courseRepository.save(new Course("cs_101"));

        int studentCount = 3;
        for (int i = 1; i <= studentCount; i++) {
            Student student = new Student("student_" + i);
            student.enroll(course);
            studentRepository.save(student);
        }

        // push changes to the database and clear the existing entities 
        // to make the subsequent operations load from the database
        entityManager.flush();
        entityManager.clear();

        Optional<Course> savedCourse = courseRepository.findById(course.getId());
        assertTrue(savedCourse.isPresent());
        assertEquals(studentCount, savedCourse.get().getEnrollments().size());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the warning said, your Enrollment is not registered in Hibernate. If you really don't need it. Please use transient annotation.  read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154622/why-does-jpa-have-a-transient-annotation)