# How to populate a custom attribute in ProdctData JSON?

Tags: java, json, sap-commerce-cloud, populate, converters

I am trying to fetch product data based on some request criteria. When I am converting the productmodel to productdata using convertors and populators i am getting all the product data in response.

I had tried to set the string value while converting & populating the productmodel data to productdata but its not helpful!!

```
{
     "products": [
         {
           //Getting from Product Model
           "name" : "ABC"
           "desc" : "abcde"
           "Quantity": 2"

           //Not from Product Model
           "matcode" : "001100"
         },
     ]
 }
```

is it possible to set one more string value(`String matcode ="ABC"`) inside the same response?

Comment: Means, you want to append one more attribute `matcode` in existing json given above?

Comment: @TayyabRazaq  Yes exactly but that is not present in productmodel

Comment: Alright, there is no issue if it's not in product model but you can extend the product model.

Comment: Are you getting product model in response of http call? Secondly, how will you set the value of matcode?

Comment: @TayyabRazaq Yes i am getting productmodel data attributes in response....i am unable to set matcode so tats y wanted help on this how to do this if its possible?

Comment: Oh, I got it. product is your entity. You can mark `matcode` with `Transient` annoation using `javax.persistence.Transient`. This way, this attribute will not change anything in your model.

Comment: Can you please share your Product.java?

Comment: @TayyabRazaq Product.java contains only three attributes as i mentioned above (name,desc,quantity)  as of now

Comment: There will be different approaches when you populate product model from an http request and when you read from database. So, what is our case?

Comment: @TayyabRazaq i am getting data from databse using flexible search query

Comment: Would be good if you add  code snippet of your populator and controller. Ideally, you just have to declare new attribute for ProductData( using `*bean.xml`) and set it up in the populator and you are done!

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, if you set `matcode`(a attribute) in ProductData correctly it gets reflected in the response

Decare  **matcode** attribute inside ProducctData by declaring it in your `*beans.xml`, something like.

```
<bean class="de.hybris.platform.commercefacades.product.data.ProductData">
    <!-- other attributes -->
    <property name="matcode" type="java.util.Set&lt;java.lang.String>"/>
</bean>
```

Now inside populator, set the `matcode` attribute value and you are done. Debug your controller and see whether you custom attribute value is there in product data. If it's there then it'll get converted to JSON correctly.

```
@Override
public void populate(final SOURCE productModel, final TARGET productData) throws ConversionException
{
    //... other codes
    productData.setMatcode("001100"); // add your logic to set this value
}
```

Comment: Just a note since the title mentions JSON. To add the attribute to your OCC webservices, you need to define the attribute to ProductWsDTO in *commercewebservices-beans.xml and add a mapping to dto-level-mappings-v2-spring.xml.

Comment: Yeah, but here SO was trying to get ProductData as Json Obj on the storefront

Answer (score 0):

If you're using hql, you can do it like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product {

      @Column(name = "name")
      private String name;

      @Column(name = "desc")
      private String desc;

      @Column(name = "quantity")
      private Integer quantity;

      @Transient
      @Column(name = "quantity")
      private String matcode;

      public Product(String name, String desc, Integer quantity, String matcode) {
         this.name = name;
         this.desc = desc;
         this.quantity = quantity;
         this.matcode = matcode;
     }

}
```

If you want to read more about `Transient` annotation, please follow [Transient Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154622/why-does-jpa-have-a-transient-annotation)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library like gson.
Assuming you have model like this:

```
public class Products
{
    private List<Product> products;
}


public class Product
{
    private String name;

    private String desc;

    private String Quantity;
}
```

Easy way:

Add another attribute to Product model

```
  private String matcode;
```

Now below code could be used:

```
  Gson gson = new Gson();
  String jsonOutput = "{\"products\": [{ \"name\" : \"ABC\" ,\"desc\" : \"abcde\", \"Quantity\": \"2\"}]}";
  Products products = gson.fromJson(jsonOutput, Products.class);
  System.out.println(products);

  for(Product p : products.getProducts()){
    p.setMatcode("001100");
  }

 System.out.println(gson.toJson(products));
```

Another longer path :

a. read the JSON response
b. convert to object ( which you should be already doing )
c. use gson to convert object to JsonElement as array
d. iterate and update the JsonObject as you require
e. convert the updated JsonElement to String output.

Working code below:

```
 Gson gson = new Gson();
 String jsonOutput = "{\"products\": [{ \"name\" : \"ABC\" ,\"desc\" : \"abcde\", \"Quantity\": \"2\"}]}";
 Products products = gson.fromJson(jsonOutput, Products.class);
 System.out.println(products);

 JsonElement jsonElement = gson.toJsonTree(products);
 JsonArray jsonArray = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().get("products").getAsJsonArray();
 for (JsonElement ele : jsonArray) {
     JsonObject obj = ele.getAsJsonObject();
     obj.addProperty("matcode", "001100");
 }
 String updatedJsonOutput = gson.toJson(jsonElement); 
 System.out.println("Updated json Object: " + updatedJsonOutput);
```