# What the difference between @Transient annotation and transient modifier

Tags: interface, annotations, javabeans, transient, modifier

Let's say i have an entity like this. What the difference between field a and b?

```
public class Human implements Serializable{
   public transient String a;

   @Transient
   public String b;

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does JPA have a @Transient annotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154622/why-does-jpa-have-a-transient-annotation)

Answer (score 3):

`transient` is about not **serializing** the field when `@Transient` is about not **persisting** the field