# How to avoid auto creation column into database? Spring

Tags: java, spring, database, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring and it's automatically creating columns. I want some of columns be created but some not.Here is example where Spring creating all 3 columns but I want only `money` to be created which is annotated with `@Cloumn`:

```
 @Column(name = FLD_MONEY,unique = false,nullable = true)
    private FastMoney money;

    private String currencyUnit;

    private BigDecimal moneyn;
```

How I can do that?

**Another question is that how I can tell to store `String` instead of Binary Data for this `column`:**

```
 @Column(name = FLD_MONEY,unique = false,nullable = true)
    private FastMoney money;
```

In database it's writing binary data but I want to see String, is it possible or not?

Comment: Can you please check this answer- https://stackoverflow.com/a/2154778/6332074

Answer (score 0):

For first question answer is just add annotation @Transient and it won't store in database.Answer gave in comments below the question